# Can I change interpolation method of a scaled Android View or are there any workarounds?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, textureview

On iOS I can achieve this by just setting a property. But on Android it seems I'm out of luck.

I need render an image of a fixed size with OpenGL, and apply it to the screen with `nearest neighbor` interpolation.

Currently I can only do this by render the image to a texture, and draw the texture to the SurfaceTexture.

This is OK except that the memory usage is horrible. On iOS I need no more than a surface the same size as the image, while on Android I need a texture that can contain the image and a double-buffered surface of the size of the much larger TextureView. Not to mention there is maximum memory usage limit on Android.

Comment: You need the texture you want to draw, and a Surface to draw on (SurfaceView or TextureView), which will be composited with the rest of the View elements.  There is no provision in the API for direct rendering with GLES onto the View layer, though a custom View with hardware acceleration will likely use that path.  In the (deleted) answer comments you say, "I need a TextureView being displayed unfiltered, not a bitmap" -- I take it you want to pass a small GLES texture to TextureView and have it do nearest-neighbor scaling when rendering?  (no API for that)

Comment: @fadden Actually I need the SurfaceTexture to be smaller than the TextureView or the TextureView to be smaller than its displayed size while the displayed content not filtered bi-linearly. Passing a small texture (I guess you mean passing a small SurfaceTexture though, that's not what I'm doing) is what I'm currently doing, but it's wasting too much memory. Actually the memory usage is OK by now. I just hope that it could be as memory efficient as its iOS counter part, since we don't have as much memory as we have on iOS.

Comment: I don't understand your memory concern unless you are on a heavily constrained device (and if it's a custom device, you could modify the API).  The only fixed app memory limit is for Dalvik/Art heap allocations; the native (malloc) heap and GPU resources are not part of that.  So long as you release everything when the app is placed into the background you shouldn't have any problems from an over-sized TextureView.  If for some reason you have a large number of TextureViews that could be an issue, but at some point you'd want a single SurfaceView and fully custom rendering.

Comment: If you haven't seen it yet: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html .  I don't know of a way to switch from bilinear to nearest-neighbor with View classes without rendering at full size.

Comment: @fadden Yeah, never knew about this document... I will read it. Guess I'm not concerning the memory usage, for now. I just feel unfair that for the same task Android needs several times the memory than iOS.

Comment: @fadden About the native heap, I've no solid proof, but it seems native allocation does count against the limit, at least before 4.2. It just doesn't count by the GC trigger. That is native allocations will make the app out of memory while there are still unreferenced objects for some older systems.

Comment: The per-app limit -- the thing that will earn you an "out of memory" error from code written in the Java programming language -- only applies to the managed (Dalvik) heap. You can call malloc() all day and not affect that. The only thing that cares is the kernel low-memory killer, but it won't kill a foreground process until it has killed nearly everything else in the system. The foreground app is expected to be sitting on a bunch of memory that it releases at pause time. Just be a good citizen and don't go too crazy so your app doesn't force a bunch of others out, and all will be well. :-)

Comment: @fadden Then guess it could be actually the pixels of a Bitmap cannot trigger GC. It was two years ago I found that problem, and I find I forgot if I had tested with native allocation or Bitmap creation :( poor memory...

Comment: @fadden And the scaling thing. So there is no way controlling how the content of a TextureView is composed? And non-TextureView Views actually share the Activity's Surface? So if I were really crazy I could actually download the pixels and create a Bitmap and draw the Bitmap to a View's canvas to achieve the effect with less memory usage?

Comment: Bitmap pixel storage has evolved over time, but it does count against the managed heap (you're probably thinking of the "external allocation" accounting mechanism).  I'm not aware of a way to change the TextureView's sampling method.  All Views, including TextureView, are composed onto a single layer by the application.  SurfaceView has an additional layer that is composited by SurfaceFlinger.  Some View drawing ops are done with GLES unless you turn acceleration off; see   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html